# How to get the username through an id in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create an offers forum, where some user can create their offers in order to provide their services and I want to show the name of the person that created that offer instead of the id.

In my database I have the two tables:

- Offers table:
  [image: Offers table]
- User table:

[image: Users table]

In offers I have a column of the professor_id, that is related to the id of users table.

This is what i have in my controller to show the offers:

```
public function ofertes(){

    $ofertes = Oferta::all()->sortByDesc('id');

    return view('create.ofertes')->with(compact('ofertes'));
}
```

and in the blade.php I have that code:

```
@foreach($ofertes as $oferta)
    <tr>
        <td>Nom : {{$oferta->professor_id}}</td> <br>
        <td>Títol : {{$oferta->titol}}</td> <br>
        <td>Descripció: {{$oferta->descripcio}}</td> <br>
        <td>Data: {{$oferta->created_at}}</td> <br><br>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

and that is what is shown:
[image: ofertes.blade.php]

Where it says nom, how I can show the name instead of the id?

Thank you!

Comment: did you tried changing $oferta->professor_id to $oferta->nom

Comment: Hey! Yes I've tried, but the thing is that nom comes from another table and the problem is that I don't know how the get it

Comment: then look into joining tables in laravel, I am currently on mobile and can't help you

Comment: Are those email addresses in the user table screenshot real or just fakes? If they're real: Please remove the screenshot as you're exposing them and also potentially violating GDPR.

Comment: There is no problem, they are completely fake

Comment: Ok, then go on :)

Comment: Please share the database structure, and sample data, in text form, not as images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have specified the relationship to `professor` in your Oferta model you can use the following code:

```
public function ofertes(){

    $ofertes = Oferta::with('professor')->latest()->get();

    return view('create.ofertes')->with(compact('ofertes'));
}
```

Your blade:

```
@foreach($ofertes as $oferta)
    <tr>
        <td>Nom : {{$oferta->professor->nom}}</td> <br>
        <td>Títol : {{$oferta->titol}}</td> <br>
        <td>Descripció: {{$oferta->descripcio}}</td> <br>
        <td>Data: {{$oferta->created_at}}</td> <br><br>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

If you haven't specified the relation you should add the following method to your Oferta model (you might need to tweak this a little bit based on your namespaces):

```
public function professor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: Good to hear, I'm glad it helped you out! You can select this answer as solution for your problem so it might even help other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy

```
public function ofertes(){

    $ofertes = Oferta::with('professor')->latest()->get();
    $users = User::all();

    return view('create.ofertes')->with(compact('ofertes', 'users'));
}

In blade file:

<td>Nom : @foreach ($users as $user)
           @if ($oferta->professor_id === $user->id) $user->nom $user->cognom
           @endif
          @endforeach
</td><br>
```

Answer (score -2):

Join two table like

```
$oferta = DB::table('users')
        ->join('offers','users.id','=','offers.professor_id')
        ->select('offers.*','users.nom')
        ->orderby('offers.id','DESC')->get();
```

Then in place of `{{$oferta->professor_id}}`, replace `{{$oferta->nom}}`

Your problem should be solved

Comment: It's better if eloquent is used in such cases, since eloquent will return a user model with a professor model which is a better thing to do in an MVC framework

Comment: doesn't matter , we only need the array or object.

Comment: u think DB::query is set as officials like for just show up ??

Comment: you answer will work but using eloquent is the correct approach, that's all i'm saying

Comment: This aproach is totally valid and more performant and the usual eloquent way.

Comment: It's slightly faster but the eloquent approach is better imo more consistent and more aligned with the laravel /OOP conventions (also more readability & flexibility) also i don't believe performance is a big deal here.